# AngularUI map binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm working with the angularJS and the AngularJS UI modules for loading gmaps on my app and perform actions on its events. The problem is that the ui-events call function doesn't pass the write parameters, indeed it doesn't pass anything to the module.

**Here is my app module**

```
angular.module('Maptesting', ['ui.map', 'ui.event'])
.controller('CtrlGMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-54.798112, -68.303375),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    $scope.myMarkers = [];


    $scope.addMarker = function ($event, $params) {
        $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Markers({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: $event.latLng
        }));
    };

    $scope.markerClicked = function(m) {
        window.alert("clicked");
    };
}]);
```

**And this is the map element where I make the calls with ui-events**

```
<div ui-map="myMap"
  ui-options="mapOptions" 
  ui-event="{ 'map-click' : 'addMarker($event)'}"
  class="map-canvas">
</div>
```

Whenever I click on the map it return me this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latLng' of null
```

I know that the error is because the $event is null but I don't know where this should be setted.

Here is the complete project: https://github.com/facuferrari/Climbing-App

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Turns out you will get this error if you do not have JQuery loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Loading jQuery is not enough. You have to load jQuery BEFORE angular.  That should fix the problem.